# How to compute the distance between two matrices conditional on an index in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, distance

I have information referring to groups of products stored in two matrices:

- First matrix: is relatively small, contains one row per group, and then some numerical variables
- Second matrix: it is large. Contains multiple rows per group and then some numerical variables.

As a minimal code example, see the following:

```
df_with_group_values = data.frame(
  group= 1:6, 
  matrix(rnorm(mean=100, 30), nrow=6))

df_with_data = data.frame(
  product_id = 1:1000,
  group = sample(6, 1000, replace=T),
  matrix(rnorm(mean=100, 5000), nrow=1000))
```

The matrix `df_with_group_values`has only 6 rows (one per group) and then 6 columns: 1 referring to the group and 5 other numerical variables. The matrix `df_with_data` contains 1000 rows and 6 columns.

I want, for each group index, to compute the distance (here I am considering a weighted euclidean distance) between the associated row in the dataset `df_with_group_values`, and all the rows referring to that group index in `df_with_data`.

I could do this by doing a `for` loop that iterates on the group index and subsetting at each iteration the large matrix, as I show here:

```
  unique_group_idx = df_with_mean_values$group
  weights = rnorm(5)
  
  for(idx in seq_along(unique_group_idx))
  {
    filtered_df_with_data = df_with_data %>% 
      filter(group == unique_group_idx[idx])
    matrix_mean = matrix(rep(as.numeric(df_with_mean_values[idx, -1]), nrow(filtered_df_with_data)), nrow=nrow(filtered_df_with_data), byrow=TRUE)
    distance = sqrt(rowMeans(weights * (filtered_df_with_data[,3:7] - matrix_mean)^2))
    
    if(idx == 1)
    {
      df_distancias = data.frame(product_id = filtered_df_with_data$product_id,
                                 distance = distance)
    } else{
      df_distancias = df_distancias %>% 
        rbind(data.frame(product_id = filtered_df_with_data$product_id, distance = distance))
    }
  }
  df_distancias = df_distancias %>% arrange(product_id)
```

But I was looking for something faster as this can get slow when the number of groups increase, and maybe more elegant. I have been thinking on how I could use the group_by function, as this seems a case where it could fit, but I got nothing so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this with `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
set.seed(123)
df_with_group_values = data.frame(
  group= 1:6, 
  matrix(rnorm(mean=100, 30), nrow=6))

df_with_data = data.frame(
  product_id = 1:1000,
  group = sample(6, 1000, replace=T),
  matrix(rnorm(mean=100, 5000), nrow=1000))

weights = rnorm(5)
weights <- exp(weights)/sum(exp(weights))

df_with_data <- setNames(df_with_data, c("product_id", "group",  paste0("d_", 1:5)))
df_with_group_values <- setNames(df_with_group_values, c("group",  paste0("g_", 1:5)))
weight_data <- do.call(data.frame, as.list(weights))
weight_data <- setNames(weight_data, paste0("w_", 1:5))

df_distancias <- df_with_data %>% 
  left_join(df_with_group_values,  by="group") %>% 
  bind_cols(weight_data) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c("product_id", "group"), names_pattern="(.*)_(.*)", names_to=c(".value", "dim")) %>% 
  group_by(product_id, group) %>% 
  summarise(distance = sqrt(mean(weights*(d-g)^2))) 
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'product_id'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.

df_distancias
#> # A tibble: 1,000 × 3
#> # Groups:   product_id [1,000]
#>    product_id group distance
#>         <int> <int>    <dbl>
#>  1          1     5    0.693
#>  2          2     4    0.363
#>  3          3     5    0.674
#>  4          4     2    0.393
#>  5          5     1    0.423
#>  6          6     1    0.301
#>  7          7     3    0.488
#>  8          8     1    0.774
#>  9          9     6    0.439
#> 10         10     5    0.653
#> # … with 990 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>